# Not A Working Code but i wanted to ask why initialising through class name has higher preference than objects?

Tags: class, object, variables, scope, static

```
//given a static variable

static int i;

//assume it is a part of class Student 
//Lets make two objects

Student s1=new Student();

Student s2=new Student();

//Here's The main deal

s1.i=20;

s2.i=22;

Student.i=27;

//The final output if you print i is 27.

System.out.println(s1.i); //27

System.out.println(s2.i);  //27

System.out.println(Student.i);  //27



//Why so?
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called
>   static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class,
>   rather than with any object.

Here is concept around it

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

In your case, `i` is a static variable and it is associated with class rather than object.

So literally there is only one variable `i` for all objects. That's the reason you see same value getting printed for all your print statements (with last updated value).